# Архитектура CMS

Tags: cms, архитектура

[image]
Доброго времени суток.

Я сейчас пишу свою CMS и архитектура примерно такая, как на изображении (терминология у меня своя). Модули общаются с объектом Application, посылая ему запросы типа get, set и т.п. Application обрабатывает эти запросы и перенаправляет их Controller'у, который уже работает с хранилищем данных. Придумывая эту архитектуру, я ориентировался на заменяемость элементов CMS. В частности, хотелось дать возможность программисту быстро перекинуть CMS с файлов на БД и обратно и обеспечить API для создания модулей.

Собственно, вопрос: просьба оценить мое решение и подсказать, как можно улучшить эту архитектуру. И какие еще бывают варианты?

Comment: MVC, MVP, MVVM

Comment: Нарисуйте нам где тут у вас шаблонизатор, тогда сможем пообщаться более конструктивно.

Comment: Гм. Ок, изменил изображение. Модули работают через шаблонизатор, сгенерированный код которого выдается пользователю.

Comment: я вот не могу понять, какую роль выполняет ваш ``Controller``? он позволяет взаимодействовать с разными ``Данными``, с разными ``Application-ами`` или это обычный посредник?

Comment: Все верно. Как я и писал ранее, Controller был создан для легкого "перекидывания" CMS с файлов на БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > В частности, хотелось дать возможность программисту быстро перекинуть CMS с файлов на БД и обратно

Прочитайте про паттерн стратегия.

Или же, создаём 2 класса

CustomDBData
CustomFileData

и собвственно класс Data extends `нужный_метод_работы`

Comment: Интересный подход, спасибо).

Answer (score 1):

На первый взгляд, класическая форма, за сиключение того что я не понимаю что такое у вас контроллер, и темболее апликатион. В остальном эта же схема пременена в движке http://danneo.com/ , могу список продолжить. К автору темы вопрос.

1. Как ваша модель защищена от дикого расплодника шаблонов?
2. Если клиент попросит отправить письмо лингвисту который работает у них на фирме, каждый раз когда добавляется новая статья. Как вы реализуете это не затронув код системы с помощью дополнительного модуля или компонента.
3. Как вы собираетесь организовать кеширование страниц? Для каждого модуля свой кеш? Или есть идеии создать что-то такое более менее не слишком запутатное с указателями на тип и владельца кеша?
4. Судя по рисунку, отдавать штмл вы собираетесь в самом конце, когда код цмс почти полностью отработал. Смелое решение, полагаю речь идет о высокой производительности. Прокомментируйте пожалуйста в чем именно вы видите плюсы данного подхода?

Comment: 1. Никак. Собственно, я это считаю плюсом - на каждое действие иметь свой шаблон. Шаблонизатор также позволяет иметь один шаблон на несколько действий - это уже вопрос к программисту. Чтобы не запутаться, шаблоны следует называть в виде `module_action.html`.  
2. Тоже никак - только дописывать уже существующий. Хотя движок также позволяет перегрузить функции класса модуля.  
3. Вот эту тему я как раз курю. Как посоветуете, кроме серверного уровня?  
4. Плюсы - одно echo на все, код можно редактировать еще до вывода, осуществить вывод еще и в файл, кинуть header.

Comment: В таком случае мне нечего добавить. Желаю вам удачи и вдохновения. Понимание проблем придет позже.

Answer (score 1):

только по этой картинке сложно дать оценку.
В каждой конкретной ситуации та или иная архитектура может быть более выгодной.
Но главный вопрос в реализации.

По ходу дела могут возникнуть нюансы и архитектуру придется поменять или исправить.

Если контроллер проверяет прав-доступы, то хочу сказать,
,что в моей CMS контроллер - это отельный модуль, и другие модули в случае необходимости могут пользоваться его услугами. А так-же самостоятельно влиять на права-доступы в случае необходимости, что дает большую свободу. А некоторые данные могут передаваться вообще минуя контроллер.

Модули же подключаются динамически по мере необходимости.

В общем я думаю что вообще не стоит задумываться о жестко-закрепленной архитектуре.

Comment: >это ОТЕЛЬНЫЙ модуль, и другие модули в случае необходимости могут пользоваться его услугами

Ночевать там за деньги?
извините, не удержался=)

Comment: Ну, модули могут работать и минуя контроллер - это все на совести автора модуля. Но для совместимости лучше через него. =)